# How to catch pattern error in input field in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, forms

I built a function catch error but it works correctly only for standard HTML5 validation,if i use ng-pattern it cannot catch the error:( How can it be made? Maybe something like  `if(error.login$invalid)`.

Template:

```
<input type="text" name="login" class="form-input"
    ng-model="newUser.login"
    ng-pattern="loginPattern"
    required>
<div class="error"
    ng-show="registrationForm.login.$invalid && registrationForm.login.$dirty">
    {{getSigningError(registrationForm.login.$error)}}
</div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.getSigningError = function(error){
    if(angular.isDefined(error)){
        if(error.required){
            return "Field shouln`t be empty"
        }
        if(error.email){
            return "Enter correct email"
        }
        if(error.login){
            return "Enter correct login"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What about `error.pattern`? Or maybe you can handle it from the template side like this: `<span ng-if="myForm.login.$error.pattern">Invalid Pattern</span>`

Comment: ow thanks,didnt know about .pattern thing:)It worked!

Comment: @Lenilson de Castro maybe you know some class for this to style like .ng-invalid?

Comment: Well, you can find it pretty easily just by inspecting the `ng-pattern` field. Like other validators, this will add the `ng-invalid` and the specific class for the pattern validator `ng-invalid-pattern`.

Comment: thanks again you helped a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `error.pattern` on your conditions like the code bellow:

```
if(error.pattern){
    return "Enter the correct format"
}
```

Or you can handle it from the template side using this:

```
<span ng-if="myForm.login.$error.pattern">Invalid Pattern</span>
```

**Observation:** `ngPattern`, like other validators, will add the `ng-invalid` and the specific class for the pattern validator `ng-invalid-pattern`. So if you want to apply specific styles for this kind of errors you can use this class.

```
.ng-invalid-pattern  {
    color: yellow;
}
```

### Refs

[Forms](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms)

Comment: idea with ng-if is probably the best choise for me

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't passing error, you can check like your controller:

```
if ($scope.formName.ControlName.$error.pattern) {}
```

`$scope.formName.ControlName.$error.pattern` will be undefined when pattern validation passed and valid otherwise.